# RichCommandMenuItem with parameter

Tags: oracle-adf

I added up a RichCommandMenuItem on my jspx, but I have no idea about passing URL parameter.
Here is my source code for the Menu.

```
RichCommandMenuItem menuPage1 = new RichCommandMenuItem();
menuPage1.setId("page1");
menuPage1.setText("Page 1");
menuPage1.setActionExpression(getMethodExpression("page1?par=123"));
```

I would like to send a parameter with my RichCommandMenuItem.
if you have any ideas or suggestions, let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Please always state the version of JDeveloper you're using when posting questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Command` controls are for navigation within ADF applications in 11g.  `Go` controls are for navigation to external URLs.  As such you're using the wrong type of component, use RichGoMenuItem instead, and it's setDestination method.

http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/apidocs/oracle/adf/view/rich/component/rich/nav/RichGoMenuItem.html